# Equivalent function in Mono.cecil

Tags: types, mono.cecil, system.type

What is the equivalent function of `Type.MakeByRefType()` in *Mono.Cecil* ?

For example:

```
Type xArgTypeDef;
xArgTypeDef = _method.DeclaringType;
xArgType.MakeByRefType()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TypeReference type = _method.DeclaringType;
ByReferenceType byRef = new ByReferenceType(type);
```

Easy as pie.